# Minha controller não encontra a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Fiz um *controller* chamado `Email`. Na `ActionResult` eu dou um Add View e crio a view. Quando eu clico com o botão direito em cima da `ActionResult` e dou um `Go to View`, diz que não encontrou a view, mas se clico com direito em cima da View e dou um `Go to Controller` ele acha o *Controller*. O que pode estar errado?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o nome da *View*? Existe um arquivo de extensão `.cshtml` com o mesmo nome da *Action* num diretório dentro de `Views` com o mesmo nome do *Controller*?

Comment: Sim, a View se chama Email.cshtml.A mensagem é: `Unable to find a matching view`

Comment: Alguma coisa na nomenclatura deve estar errada. Pode tirar uma foto da tela com o Visual Studio e colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: O *Controller* é `EmailController` e a *View* é `Email` também? Ali não vejo uma *Action* `Email`. Vejo só o *Scaffold* padrão.

Comment: Foi mal pessoal. Eu tive que refazer o projeto e dessa vez esqueci de renomear de Index para Email a Controller. Peço descilpas a todos. Valeu @CiganoMorrisonMendez, obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É algum problema de nomenclatura. Pela foto que você tirou, não vejo a *Action* `Email` no seu `EmailController`.

Experimente criar a *Action* e tente novamente.